# pedagogy vs. teaching tags

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

[pedagogy](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pedagogy) should almost certainly be a tag on music.SE. [teaching](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teaching) already exists, as does [learning](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning).

Perhaps [teaching](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teaching) or [pedagogy](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pedagogy) should be made a synonym of the other? And is there a significant difference in the questions that would be tagged [learning](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning) vs. one that would be tagged [pedagogy](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pedagogy)?

Ref: [How can a classical pianist learn jazz piano?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/410/133)

Comment: Does SE have some kind of functionality for identifying/querying synonymous tags?

Comment: @Rei At the bottom of the Tags page there's a link to view tag synonyms.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think the distinction is important here; we don't want questions purely about the art of teaching (pedagogy), but teaching questions relating to music.  It all falls under teaching anyways.  I'd make [pedagogy](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pedagogy) a synonym of [teaching](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teaching).

Comment: Hm, I'd actually say that teaching and pedagogy are close enough to be synonymous especially for the purpose of doing a site-wide search, while `learning` and `pedagogy` aren't necessarily related. For instance, I can learn violin without anyone engaging in the act of teaching other than to say I'm currently teaching myself (and take it from me, I really wish I had a teacher right now).

Comment: @ReiMiyasaka Wow, I did not mean to put `learning` there.  Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 1):

My first reaction would be to say, like the asker, that [pedagogy](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pedagogy) should be a synonym of [teaching](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teaching), for questions of the kind:

- "How do you prevent this [*specific default of playing an instrument*] in a [*optional adjective*] pupil when teaching [*broader technical category*] ?"
- "Do you begin teaching [*technique X*] or [*technique Y*] before [*technique Z*] ?"

And that [autodidact](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/autodidact) be a synonym of [learning](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning) or vice-versa, because most of the

- "How do you learn [*technique X*] ?"
- "How can [*A member of X*] become [*A member of Y*] ?"

questions are in fact *self-learning* questions.

Comment: True, but is there really any difference in the answers to those questions? I'd almost say we could make both `learning` and `teaching` synonyms of `pedagogy`.

Comment: @NReilingh: No, @ReiMiyasaka has mentioned why that wouldn't be a good idea.

Comment: What about the question "Where can I find a good flute teacher?" or something along those lines that I saw.  I would tag that as learning because you are searching for a way to better yourself, but I wouldn't say it is self-learning.  Pedagogy and teaching I believe should be synonyms though.